# MediaPlayer looping video freezes after 1st or 2nd loop

Tags: unreal-5, video

I am trying to make a VHS effect for my game in UE5, using a looping MP4 video for the user interface. The video just freezes after the 1st or 2nd loop during test in viewport.

[image: Playback settings]

I tried to set different scalability groups or load different videos, but the problem persists.

How can I make this video loop endlessly with no freezing?